# Will a refusal to enter the US mean I can't enter Canada either?

Tags: usa, canada, denial-of-entry

In October 2020 I arrived in the US on a visitor's visa for a 5 day vacation. I was deported on arrival (at the airport), and barred for 5 years from the US.  The US CBP officers asked me a ton load of questions but I am not completely sure which laws I might have violated when I told them I would be renewing my U.S. driver's license again. I was immediately placed in a cell. The deportation papers stated "presumption of employment".

I would now like to visit and engage some of my ex-coworker friends in Canada. Am I barred from Canada too?

[image]

Comment: Your intention to renew your driver's license for a five day vacation was probably construed by CBP as an intention to immigrate. Do you need a visa to visit Canada? Which nationalities do you hold?

Comment: For completeness, when were you barred?

Comment: Yes, I do need a visa to visit Canada. This incident occurred in October, last year (2020). I am from a country where people love to eat curried goat and white rice. So maybe that played a factor especially since many Americans keep goats as pets.

Comment: Holding and renewing a driver’s license may require you to be resident in the issuing state. it can be used as one of the I9 documents. You were planning to claim to be resident in a state, which contradicts claiming to be a visitor.

Comment: @megatr0n Is that a joke? I'm totally baffled

Comment: @megatr0n I think you'll find the idea of having a pet goat (though not unheard of) would be strange to most Americans, but I imagine that depends on the part of the country as well.

Comment: At least in the Greater Toronto area I would guess that a larger fraction of the population likes to eat goat rather than keep them as pets

Comment: @BenBolker Can confirm. Curried goat and jerk chicken (Jamaican), and curried goat and white rice (South Asian) are everywhere. Goats as pets, only old two-legged ones.

Comment: What was the reason you wanted to renew a driver's license? That doesn't even make since how you could do it in as little as 5 days. If you are just coming for a short trip you would just want an International Driving Permit and your home country license.

Comment: Eating goat is "strange to Americans?" Sheesh, I live in the UK and goat curry is even on the menu at my local hospital (along with lots of other "ethnic minority" dishes).

Comment: Here in Connecticut my local Indian restaurant makes a Goat Curry Special.

Comment: Ironically the first time I had goat was in the US, Seattle in fact (I think it was a Jamaican dish), I'm from New Zealand where it's not a common meat animal. But perhaps this is a roundabout way of implying racial profiling may have played a part in the original deportation?

Comment: I would not call this a deportation. Do you have any official doc calling it deportation? You certainly were denied entry, but that's legally another thing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Pitter patter, let's get at'er, strap in your horn and comb yer flow.

Comment: @alephzero it might be strange to some (just like it's probably strange to some in the UK), but you can find it easily in any major city. Local hospitals in those major cities likely have it as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no automatic ban for Canada if you are banned from the United States.

However, because you have to apply for a visa to visit Canada, you will be asked to provide any information about visa denials, refusal of entries as well as deportation/removal proceedings against you in other countries.

Because your incident happened fairly recently, you will face significant challenges when applying for the Canadian visa. You will have to convince the Canadian authority that you will leave at the end of the stay and will not do any unauthorized work during your stay.

A deportation record from the U.S. for immigration intent or presumption of employment will be a heavy mark against you in this regard.

In your case, I do not think it will be worth it to even try, at least not without advice from a qualified Canadian immigration consultant/lawyer (who might also just tell you the chances are slim to none).

But due to the Covid situation, I would not recommend you to apply for a visitor visa for non-essential reasons anyway.

Comment: +1 My advice is for him to forget North America for an extended period.

Comment: Exceptionally good advice because piling refusal on top of refusal will just make things a lot worse.

Comment: If OP ends up applying anyway, they better have a much better explanation for what happened with their US refusal. *"I just wanted to visit the US, get an US licence renewed, and then travel home without immigration intent"* sounds fishy to us well-meaning people on the Internet, it sounded fishy to the US immigration officer, and it will also sound fishy to the Canadian immigration officer. Half-hearted appeals to racism will not make that problem go away.

Comment: @user56513 Wait, what's wrong with Mexico again please?

Comment: @tchrist COVID-19 presumably?

Comment: I would not call this a deportation. Per own comment above

Comment: @QuoraFeans If OP was told by CBP that he was barred from the U.S. for five years, he was removed. Given the seriousness of the alleged immigration violation, he was likely sent for expedited removal instead of being offered an option to withdrawal. Voluntary withdrawal usually doesn't involve being put in a holding cell. But a clarification from OP would be helpful.

Comment: @tchrist Last I checked on my atlas Mexico is in Antarctica.

Comment: I spent about a day and a half locked up in C.B.P's ice box. I still haven't caught COVID-19. I think this is due to the fact that I kept moving and pacing around the cell to avoid sleeping or leaning against the walls. I wasn't on a hunger-strike or fasting. I couldn't eat that jelly thing they claimed was fruit. I am cutting my losses and moving on instead of paying some lawyer, who will pretend to help while already knowing this is basically beating a dead donkey. The challenge I face now is learning to communicate in a another language. Thanks to all the posters.